# Regression in a ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to write a code for a shinyApp in which I select a response variable (just one select box) and then I selct all the covariates that I want in checkbox. Moreover I would like to specify the family of ditribution of my reponse variable (Gaussian, Poisson, Binomial, etc..). I don't know what to write in the main panel and in the server. Could someone help me?

```
library(shiny) 
library(plotly)
data(iris)

ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Regression"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("var",label="Choose the response variable:",choice=names(iris), selectize=FALSE),
    tags$hr(),
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId ="ind_var",label = "Select at least two independent variables:", choices = names(iris)),

    mainPanel(

    )
  )
)

server<-function(input,output){


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It's very hard to say right now. What do you want to display in the main panel? What do you want the server to do? The server is where you do your calculations—what are they?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this small example can help you.

If you want to dynamically create a formula, you have to wrap it into `reformulate` or `as.formula`.

This shinyApp example prints out the summary of the linear regression and plots a prediction based on that model:

```
library(shiny) 
library(plotly)
data(iris)

ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Regression"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("var",label="Choose the response variable:",choice=names(iris), selectize=FALSE),
    tags$hr(),
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId ="ind_var", label = "Select at least two independent variables:", choices = names(iris), selected = "Species"),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot"),
      verbatimTextOutput("summary")

    )
  )
)

server<-function(input,output){

  lmR <- reactive({
    req(input$var)
    req(input$ind_var)

    ## Option 1 ---------------------
    # formula = as.formula(paste(input$var, " ~ ", paste(input$ind_var, collapse= "+")))
    # stats::lm(formula=formula, data=iris)

    # browser()
    ## Option 2 ---------------------               
    stats::lm(formula=reformulate(input$ind_var, input$var), data=iris)
  })

  output$summary <- renderPrint(width="400", {
    lmR()
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(predict(lmR()))    
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```